# MVC: Cargando lista incorrecta

Tags: c#, mvc

Saludos, ayuda por favor, cuando EDITO algun valor de las propiedades de la coleccion este no se ve reflejado en las vista retornada, por ejemplo, cuando intento EDITAR la edad me deja hacerlo, pero cuando salvo no veo reflejado el cambio, por que me está cargando una lista diferente a la que estoy editando.

```
    namespace ModelClass.Controllers
    {
        public class ClientesController : Controller
        {
            public static List<Clientes> empList = new List<Clientes>
            {
                new Clientes
                    {
                        ID = 1,
                        nombre = "Vickry",
                        FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                        edad = 30
                    },
                    new Clientes
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    nombre = "Jeneury",
                    FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                    edad = 26
                },
                new Clientes
                {
                    ID = 3,
                    nombre = "Sebas",
                    FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                    edad = 2
                }

        };

        // GET: Clientes
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Clientes = from e in empList
                           orderby e.ID
                           select e;
            return View(Clientes);
        }

        // GET: Clientes/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Clientes/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Clientes/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Clientes/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            List<Clientes> empList = TodosLosClientes();
            var Clientes = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            return View(Clientes);
        }

        // POST: Clientes/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                var Clientes = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
                if (TryValidateModel(Clientes))
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                return View(Clientes);

            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Clientes/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Clientes/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        [NonAction]
        public List<Clientes> TodosLosClientes()
        {
            return new List<Clientes>
            {
                //para agragar a la nueva lista un cliente (objeto)
                //necesariamente hay que instanciarlo tambien dentro de la lista
                new Clientes
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    nombre = "Miguel",
                    FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                    edad = 30
                },
                new Clientes
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    nombre = "Jene",
                    FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                    edad = 26
                },
                new Clientes
                {
                    ID = 3,
                    nombre = "Sebas",
                    FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                    edad = 2
                }
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Es debido a que estas usando 2 listas diferentes. En el action `Edit` que se ejecuta con `GET`, cargas la lista que retorna el metodo `TodosLosCliente()`:

```
 // GET: Clientes/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    List<Clientes> empList = TodosLosClientes();// aqui utilizas la lista que retorna este metodo
    var Clientes = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
    return View(Clientes);
}
```

Mientras que cuando editas el cliente, cargas la lista del objeto `empList` declaradado static en el controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {

        // aqui estas cargando la lista del empList statico, no del metodo TodosLosClients()
        var Clientes = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
        if (TryValidateModel(Clientes))
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        return View(Clientes);

    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Tanto el metodo `TodosLosClientes()` como la lista `empList` tiene registros diferentes lo que puede explicar que no te muestre los mismo resultados.

Comment: cambié la lista, pero no surte efecto

Comment: Depende de que forma cambiaste las listas. Estas usando sola lista para todas las operaciones?

Answer (score 1):

debes cambiar a:

```
using MiPrimerAplicacion.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MiPrimerAplicacion.Controllers
{
    public class ClientesController : Controller
    {

        public static List<Clientes> empList = new List<Clientes>
            {
                new Clientes
                    {
                        ID = 1,
                        nombre = "Vickry",
                        FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                        edad = 30
                    },
                    new Clientes
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    nombre = "Jeneury",
                    FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                    edad = 26
                },
                new Clientes
                {
                    ID = 3,
                    nombre = "Sebas",
                    FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToString()),
                    edad = 2
                }

        };

        // GET: ClientesMVC
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Clientes = from e in empList
                           orderby e.ID
                           select e;
            return View(Clientes);
        }

        // GET: ClientesMVC/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: ClientesMVC/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ClientesMVC/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: ClientesMVC/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            //List<Clientes> empList = TodosLosClientes();
            var Clientes = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            return View(Clientes);
        }

        // POST: ClientesMVC/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                var Clientes = empList.Single(m => m.ID == id);
                if (TryUpdateModel(Clientes))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");                    
                }
                return View(Clientes);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }

        // GET: ClientesMVC/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ClientesMVC/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }




    }
    }
```

en el ejemplo usa dos listas, se borra una y se usa en todo el ejemplo eso

Comment: Podrias ser mucho mas claro, sobre porque esta solucion es mejor? mira [answer]